# Why does Superboy have Pithecophobia?

Tags: character, young-justice

In Young Justice Season 1, in many episodes they get a villain related to ape/monkey family like M.O.N.Q.I.s (Mobile Optimal Neural Quotient Infiltrators), Monsieur Mallah, Ultra-Humanite etc. and Superboy constantly refers to his monkey hate (Pithecophobia). But what is the reason of Superboy's Pithecophobia? Is there any significance of it or is it just a plain in-joke only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the canon to the TV series Young Justice tie in comic #2,  the happy harbor hideout, previously home to the Justice League, was attacked by the Joker. Connor was alone in the Cave after the Young Justice team moved in, and was infected by some mind altering object. This caused him to hallucinate that there was green monkeys with jet packs, related to the previous attack by the Joker.

Needless to say, Connor found out something about himself. That he hated monkeys. It's all the Joker's fault.

This is the incident that they refer to when Batman or Red Tornado says they had to change hideouts.

[image]

[image]

***And as often as Superboy is attacked by monkeys, it's a completely rational hate.***

P.S. Superboy hates, not fears, monkeys. So it would be pithecomisia, not pithecophobia. Different Greek suffix.

Comment: When is that comics fall in chronology of the show?

Comment: @AnkitSharma between two episodes of Season 1. I'll find out the specifics when I'm not on mobile.

Comment: OK, take your time

Comment: @ankit I don't have the episode number, but this happened like a day or a month after Young Justice is formed and given the old justice League headquarters. Right after they move into Mount Justice.